# Geolocation Interface always returns 403: Access Not Configured

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

I have inputted my credit card information and bought "Google Maps API v2", "Google Maps API v3" and "Google Maps Geolocation API". I am sure that my API_key is correct. But when my android app to query the geolocation server, the server returns 403(Access Not Configured) everytime.

My project number is 663182082293, and project ID is trustgo.com:trustgo. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Email: shien01@baidu.com

Follwing is my code for the requests:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(
                "https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=AIzaSyChtmYL9zXe0XNhZQeThF8A9t_YpQ-E1p8");
        try {

            JSONObject holder = new JSONObject();
            holder.put("homeMobileCountryCode", cell.MCC);
            holder.put("homeMobileNetworkCode", cell.MNC);
            holder.put("radioType", "gsm");
            holder.put("carrier", "samsung");

            JSONObject cellTower = new JSONObject();
            cellTower.put("cellId", cell.CID);
            cellTower.put("locationAreaCode", cell.LAC);
            cellTower.put("mobileCountryCode", cell.MCC);
            cellTower.put("mobileNetworkCode", cell.MNC);
            cellTower.put("age", 0);
            cellTower.put("signalStrength", -60);
            cellTower.put("timingAdvance", 15);

            JSONArray cellTowerarray = new JSONArray();
            cellTowerarray.put(cellTower);
            holder.put("cellTowers", cellTowerarray);

            JSONObject wifiTower = new JSONObject();
            WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) MainActivity.this
                    .getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
                            Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            wm.getDhcpInfo();
            List<WifiConfiguration> list = wm.getConfiguredNetworks();
            WifiConfiguration wif;
            WifiInfo wifiInfo = wm.getConnectionInfo();
            List<ScanResult> results = wm.getScanResults();

            if (results != null && results.size() > 0) {
                JSONArray wifiTowerarray = new JSONArray();
                String wifimac = wifiInfo.getMacAddress();
                int strength = wifiInfo.getRssi();
                wifiTower.put("macAddress", wifimac);
                wifiTower.put("signalStrength", strength);
                wifiTower.put("age", 0);
                wifiTower.put("channel", 2417);
                wifiTower.put("signalToNoiseRatio", -85);
                wifiTowerarray.put(wifiTower);
                holder.put("wifiAccessPoints", wifiTowerarray);
            }

            StringEntity query = new StringEntity(holder.toString());
            query.setContentType("application/json");
            post.setEntity(query);

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent()));
            StringBuffer strBuff = new StringBuffer();
            String result = null;
            while ((result = buffReader.readLine()) != null) {
                strBuff.append(result);
            }

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(strBuff.toString());
            String str1 = json.getString("location");

            JSONObject subjosn = new JSONObject(str1);

            itude.latitude = subjosn.getString("latitude");
            itude.longitude = subjosn.getString("longitude");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(e.getMessage(), e.toString());
        } finally {
            post.abort();
            client = null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you Activate your Google Play Services Active from Google Play API COnsole?? If not then please check it once, Go to Google API Console-> Login with your Gmail-> On Console's left top corner click on Services-> You will see lots of Google Services there-> Select Google Maps Android API v2 and Google Maps API v2 and Google Maps API v3 and any other if you need.

Comment: Yes. I had activated these three services before. I also googled this issue to find whether anyone met the same issue before. But to be disappointed, there was few same issue before. Thanks.

Comment: After I removed the limitation of SHA1 certificate fingerprint and package name, the API worked.